# Calculate time difference on same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to get the time difference between rows per application and if the difference of time is less than 5 minutes then count as a single application.

Input:

```
AppNumber   Employee    Date        Time_generatedat
-----------------------------------------------------
143270137   shiva       23/09/2019  12:24   
143270137   shiva       23/09/2019  12:25   
143270137   shiva       23/09/2019  12:27   
143270137   shiva       23/09/2019  13:16   
12339090    kalyan      23/09/2019  08:13   
12339090    kalyan      23/09/2019  09:14
```

Output:

```
AppNumber   Employee    Date    Time_generatedat    output
-------------------------------------------------------------
143270137   shiva   23/09/2019  12:24               1
143270137   shiva   23/09/2019  12:25               1
143270137   shiva   23/09/2019  12:27               1 
143270137   shiva   23/09/2019  13:16               2
12339090    kalyan  23/09/2019  08:13               1
12339090    kalyan  23/09/2019  09:14               2
```

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What if the difference between 1st and 3rd record is 9 minutes but gap between 1-2 and 2-3 is 4.5 minutes?

Comment: if gap between 1&2 - is 9 minutes means they are two different records but if gap is 4.5 minutes it should treat as one record

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_time_generatedat > dateadd(minute, -5, time_generatedat)
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (partition by appnumber, date order by time_generatedat) as output
from (select t.*,
             lag(time_generatedat) over (partition by appnumber, date order by time_generatedat) as prev_time_generatedat
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: thank you but lag() function only applicable from sql server 2012.

Comment: @SindhuB . . . `lag()` is available in *all* supported versions of SQL Server.  Previous versions are no longer supported.